# Передать переменную с одной страницы на другую через JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, переменные, геолокация

Возникла проблема передачи переменных с одной веб-страницы на другую. Кратко опишу задачу: нужно сделать отслеживание курьера в реальном времени. Есть условно 2 веб-страницы на одном домене: одна для курьера(к примеру track.html), другая для пользователей(index.html). Нужно отслеживать местоположение курьера на track.html, передать координаты на index.html и поставить маркер на карте в полученных координатах(карта на странице index.html). По возможности планирую все сделать без обращения к серверу, но если знаете метод с сервером, так же буду благодарен.

Comment: Без сервера связать двух пользователей в принципе невозможно.

Comment: А как без сервера? Откуда данные курьера возьмутся? Вот я хочу поставить маркер курьера. Откуда возьмутся его координаты? Без сервера это кто-то должен сливать данные на какой-то сервис. Который естественно не ваш. А клиент должен иметь возможность их считать.

Comment: Окей, если через сервер, как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: Не знаю каким образом, но курьер/девайс курьера/вшитый в курьера датчик должен отсылать с определённым интервалом на сервер свой id и geo-метку. На сервере в БД записывается время, id курьера и его geo-позиционирование. На странице отслеживания на карте отображаете где он находится.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME а как же webRTC? Можно же сделать без сервера :)